# How to generate equation code representing tensors and their covariant derivatives for LaTeX and UnicodeMath using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, latex, equation

How to generate equation code representing tensors and their covariant derivatives for LaTeX and UnicodeMath using Python? (I'm not used to doing the whole "Answer your own question" thing. Feel free to edit this part so it's less horrible.)

Answer (score 2):

I have doing math regarding tensors and covariant derivatives lately and writing them out is a pain. As such, I made code to do it for me. You can tell it to output the code in LaTeX(like if you wanted to write a question on stackexchange or a research paper) or UnicodeMath(like if you wanted to manipulate the equations in a Microsoft Word document). I *think* I've worked out all the bugs and it should be ready for release. I coded it in Python 3.11.0. It could probably be improved, but doing so wouldn't change the output or make the code noticeably faster to a human. I should've probably added more comments too. I call the program "UnicodeMath-LaTeX-TensorGenV2.py". I included some examples at the top so you can get a feel for how it works. I used [this document](https://groups.oist.jp/system/files/Lecture5.pdf) as a reference for the equations. I called the variant of the covariant derivative with a superscript a "contravariant derivative" which I don't think is the right term, but I digress. I'd give an example of the LaTeX code but it won't display properly on this stackoverflow for some odd reason. Hope people find this useful! :)

```
#print(UnicodeMathChristoffelComp1("T",["\\nu ","\\rho ","\\sigma ","\\lambda "],[0,0,0,1],"\\kappa ",1,"\\mu "))
#print(UnicodeMathCovariantDerivative("T",["\\nu ","\\rho ","\\sigma ","\\lambda "],[0,0,0,1],"\\kappa ","\\theta ","\\mu "))
#print(UnicodeMathContravariantDerivative("T",["\\nu ","\\rho ","\\sigma ","\\lambda "],[0,0,0,1],"\\kappa ","\\theta ","\\phi ","\\mu "))
#print(LaTeXChristoffelComp1("T",["\\nu ","\\rho ","\\sigma ","\\lambda "],[0,0,0,1],"\\kappa ",1,"\\mu "))
#print(LaTeXCovariantDerivative("T",["\\nu ","\\rho ","\\sigma ","\\lambda "],[0,0,0,1],"\\kappa ","\\theta ","\\mu "))
#print(LaTeXContravariantDerivative("T",["\\nu ","\\rho ","\\sigma ","\\lambda "],[0,0,0,1],"\\kappa ","\\theta ","\\phi ","\\mu "))


def UnicodeMathTensorGen(T,u,covariance):
    #Replace all \'s with \\'s!
    #0 for covariant, 1 for contravariant
    n=len(covariance)
    if(n==0):
        return T
    elif(n==1):
        return T+"_^"[covariance[0]]+u[0]
    string="■(〖"+T+"〗"+"_^"[covariance[0]]+"("+u[0]
    for i in range(1,n):
        if(covariance[i]!=covariance[i-1]):
            string+=") 〖\\zwsp 〗"+"_^"[covariance[i]]+"("
        string+=u[i]
    return string+"))"
def UnicodeMathChristoffelComp1(T,u,covariance,indexvar,index,derivvar):
    string=""
    match covariance[index]:
        case 1:
            string+="+〖Γ\\zwsp〗_("+derivvar+indexvar+")^"+u[index]
        case 0:
            string+="-〖Γ\\zwsp〗_("+derivvar+u[index]+")^"+indexvar
    u[index]=indexvar
    return string+" "+UnicodeMathTensorGen(T,u,covariance)
def UnicodeMathChristoffelComp2(a,b,c,indexvar):
    return "1/2 〖g^〖"+c+indexvar+"〗〗(\partial_〖"+a+"〗 g_〖"+b+indexvar+"〗+\partial_〖"+b+"〗 g_〖"+a+indexvar+"〗-\partial_〖"+indexvar+"〗 g_〖"+a+b+"〗)"
def UnicodeMathChristoffelComp3(T,u,covariance,indexvar,indexvar2,index,derivvar):
    string=""
    match covariance[index]:
        case 1:
            string+="+"+UnicodeMathChristoffelComp2(derivvar,indexvar,u[index],indexvar2)
        case 0:
            string+="-"+UnicodeMathChristoffelComp2(derivvar,u[index],indexvar,indexvar2)
    u[index]=indexvar
    return string+" "+UnicodeMathTensorGen(T,u,covariance)
def UnicodeMathCovariantDerivative(T,u,covariance,indexvar,indexvar2,derivvar):
    string2="_〖"+derivvar+"〗 "+UnicodeMathTensorGen(T,u,covariance)
    string="\\nabla"+string2+"=\\partial"+string2
    for i in range(len(covariance)):
        string+=UnicodeMathChristoffelComp1(T,u[:],covariance,indexvar,i,derivvar)
    string+="=\\partial"+string2
    for i in range(len(covariance)):
        string+=UnicodeMathChristoffelComp3(T,u[:],covariance,indexvar,indexvar2,i,derivvar)
    return string
def UnicodeMathContravariantDerivative(T,u,covariance,indexvar,indexvar2,indexvar3,derivvar):
    string2=UnicodeMathTensorGen(T,u,covariance)
    string="\\nabla^〖"+derivvar+"〗 "+string2+"=〖g^〖"+derivvar+indexvar3+"〗〗\\nabla_〖"+indexvar3+"〗 "+string2+"=〖g^〖"+derivvar+indexvar3+"〗〗(\\partial_〖"+indexvar3+"〗 "+string2
    for i in range(len(covariance)):
        string+=UnicodeMathChristoffelComp1(T,u[:],covariance,indexvar,i,indexvar3)
    string+=")=〖g^〖"+derivvar+indexvar3+"〗〗(\\partial_〖"+indexvar3+"〗 "+string2
    for i in range(len(covariance)):
        string+=UnicodeMathChristoffelComp3(T,u[:],covariance,indexvar,indexvar2,i,indexvar3)
    return string+")"

def LaTeXTensorGen(T,u,covariance):
    n=len(covariance)
    if(n==0):
        return T
    elif(n==1):
        return T+"_^"[covariance[0]]+"{"+u[0]+"}"
    string=T+"_^"[covariance[0]]+"{"+u[0]
    for i in range(1,n):
        if(covariance[i]!=covariance[i-1]):
            string+="}{}"+"_^"[covariance[i]]+"{"
        string+=u[i]
    return string+"}"
def LaTeXChristoffelComp1(T,u,covariance,indexvar,index,derivvar):
    string=""
    match covariance[index]:
        case 1:
            string+="+Γ{}_{"+derivvar+indexvar+"}^{"+u[index]+"}"
        case 0:
            string+="-Γ{}_{"+derivvar+u[index]+"}^{"+indexvar+"}"
    u[index]=indexvar
    return string+" "+LaTeXTensorGen(T,u,covariance)
def LaTeXChristoffelComp2(a,b,c,indexvar):
    return "\\frac{1}{2}g^{"+c+indexvar+"}\\left(\\partial_{"+a+"}g_{"+b+indexvar+"}+\\partial_{"+b+"}g_{"+a+indexvar+"}-\\partial_{"+indexvar+"}g_{"+a+b+"}\\right)"
def LaTeXChristoffelComp3(T,u,covariance,indexvar,indexvar2,index,derivvar):
    string=""
    match covariance[index]:
        case 1:
            string+="+"+LaTeXChristoffelComp2(derivvar,indexvar,u[index],indexvar2)
        case 0:
            string+="-"+LaTeXChristoffelComp2(derivvar,u[index],indexvar,indexvar2)
    u[index]=indexvar
    return string+LaTeXTensorGen(T,u,covariance)
def LaTeXCovariantDerivative(T,u,covariance,indexvar,indexvar2,derivvar):
    string2="_{"+derivvar+"} "+LaTeXTensorGen(T,u,covariance)
    string="\\nabla"+string2+"=\\partial"+string2
    for i in range(len(covariance)):
        string+=LaTeXChristoffelComp1(T,u[:],covariance,indexvar,i,derivvar)
    string+="=\\partial"+string2
    for i in range(len(covariance)):
        string+=LaTeXChristoffelComp3(T,u[:],covariance,indexvar,indexvar2,i,derivvar)
    return string
def LaTeXContravariantDerivative(T,u,covariance,indexvar,indexvar2,indexvar3,derivvar):
    string2=LaTeXTensorGen(T,u,covariance)
    string="\\nabla^{"+derivvar+"}"+string2+"=g^{"+derivvar+indexvar3+"}\\nabla_{"+indexvar3+"}"+string2+"=g^{"+derivvar+indexvar3+"}\\left(\\partial_{"+indexvar3+"}"+string2
    for i in range(len(covariance)):
        string+=LaTeXChristoffelComp1(T,u[:],covariance,indexvar,i,indexvar3)
    string+="\\right)=g^{"+derivvar+indexvar3+"}\\left(\\partial_{"+indexvar3+"}"+string2
    for i in range(len(covariance)):
        string+=LaTeXChristoffelComp3(T,u[:],covariance,indexvar,indexvar2,i,indexvar3)
    return string+"\\right)"
```

Edit: Adding an answer to Tailwhip's question:

```
print(LaTeXCovariantDerivative("T",["\\nu ","\\rho ","\\sigma ","\\lambda "],[0,0,0,1],"\\kappa ","\\theta ","\\mu "))

$$\nabla_{\mu } T_{\nu \rho \sigma }{}^{\lambda }=\partial_{\mu } T_{\nu \rho \sigma }{}^{\lambda }-Γ{}_{\mu \nu }^{\kappa } T_{\kappa \rho \sigma }{}^{\lambda }-Γ{}_{\mu \rho }^{\kappa } T_{\nu \kappa \sigma }{}^{\lambda }-Γ{}_{\mu \sigma }^{\kappa } T_{\nu \rho \kappa }{}^{\lambda }+Γ{}_{\mu \kappa }^{\lambda } T_{\nu \rho \sigma }{}^{\kappa }=\partial_{\mu } T_{\nu \rho \sigma }{}^{\lambda }-\frac{1}{2}g^{\kappa \theta }\left(\partial_{\mu }g_{\nu \theta }+\partial_{\nu }g_{\mu \theta }-\partial_{\theta }g_{\mu \nu }\right)T_{\kappa \rho \sigma }{}^{\lambda }-\frac{1}{2}g^{\kappa \theta }\left(\partial_{\mu }g_{\rho \theta }+\partial_{\rho }g_{\mu \theta }-\partial_{\theta }g_{\mu \rho }\right)T_{\nu \kappa \sigma }{}^{\lambda }-\frac{1}{2}g^{\kappa \theta }\left(\partial_{\mu }g_{\sigma \theta }+\partial_{\sigma }g_{\mu \theta }-\partial_{\theta }g_{\mu \sigma }\right)T_{\nu \rho \kappa }{}^{\lambda }+\frac{1}{2}g^{\lambda \theta }\left(\partial_{\mu }g_{\kappa \theta }+\partial_{\kappa }g_{\mu \theta }-\partial_{\theta }g_{\mu \kappa }\right)T_{\nu \rho \sigma }{}^{\kappa }$$
```

Edit 2: Fixed LaTeX generating code. Apparently the physics stackexchange equation preview is messed up, which led me to upload faulty code as it was the only variant the preview said worked. Also fixed the edit I made for Tailwhip. What an aggravating bug.

Edit 3: I'm sorry how they treated you Tailwhip. Unfortunately, such toxicity is common on stackexchange. Know that your remark helped me find a bug in my code, and more importantly, in the [physics stackexchange equation preview system](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14231/99319) as well.

Comment: ... what exactly are trying to achieve? Why not making your own LaTeX commands instead? I tried to  run in LaTeX the last line you posted but the rendering wrong (the subindices are rendered for ex as `_\mu` the `_` can be seen). Did I miss anything?

Comment: @cards What the Nether?! It renders perfectly fine on the physics stackexchange but not the math stackexchange?!?!?! Why?!?!?! Well looks like there's going to be a version 2.0! To answer your first question, the LaTeX part was an afterthought, I mainly made this for Microsoft Word. Maybe making LaTeX commands would be better...

Comment: When I edited the code so that there where no \'s before _'s and ^'s, it worked on math stackexchange but broke on physics stackexchange! Gah!! I do not want to have 2 LaTeX versions! I need to figure out a way to render tensors which makes both stackexchange's happy...

Comment: @cards Ok, the code should work now! Apparently physics stackexchange is just buggy.